# How to make <button> switch to a new line when overridding the <nav>?

Tags: html, css

I have an nav and a button. Now nav can work properly when resizing the window of the browser, however the button will override the 's last item when resizing the window to a certain width, so how to solve it?

Normal thing:

[image]

Overridding:

[image]

What I want is: When resizing the width to a smaller size, it will make the button(s) to the next new line.

---

```
 <nav aria-label="primary">
  <ul>
     <li>...</li>
     ....
  </ul>
</nav>

<button class="dark-theme-switcher" type="button" aria-label="Toggle dark/light mode"></button>
```

Comment: Please add some CSS and HTML code. Also what would you want to happen when resizing is done. GEneral answer is to put it in a collapsible menu

Answer (score 0):

1. Add your button into the li property which is available under ul property. add a new class for that button and add a **margin-left** to that class (button) as you wish.

```css
.nav-btn{
  margin-left: (xx)px
}
```

```html
<nav aria-label="primary">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Services</li>
      <li>Contact Us</li>
      <li><button class="dark-theme-switcher nav-btn"...</button></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

2. Or use nav component which is available in bootstrap components - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/